# Need help configuring Sphinx on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have to configure Sphinx on the Jenkins server which does continuous integration of your builds, when we push to GITHUB. I have written tests in Rspec to test my search functionality. But cant get the tests to pass on Jenkins as Sphinx is not properly configured. Please help me with Sphinx configuration on Jenkins, if anyone has experience with that. Jenkins is setup on a Linode instance of Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

Just install sphinx as you usually do for the regular usage there, and test it with the user from those jenkins running. Works for me.
Normally jenkins has folder jobs /var/lib/jenkins/jobs where jobs are located. You can enter your project folder and test the rspec running as usual under jenkins user.

Comment: I use Thinking Sphinx gem to configure Sphinx and run indexes etc. This needs me to only setup Sphinx on any server without having it configured as ThinkingSphinx takes care of it. The problem I am facing is, the app is not indexing properly. is there any place in particular where i need to keep the indexes so that Jenkins can read/write to them? perhaps a particular folder that i need to give permissions to the Jenkins user and place configs and indexes there?

Comment: Normally indexes are storing in app_root/db/sphinx for thinking sphinx. Do you have real time indexes or you invoking indexing operation manually with schedule in production? Actually i'm wondering how it should work since jenkins for testing should use zero state environment. I guess it will be more effective to stub sphinx calls in tests. Otherwise you need to invoke indexer every time you populate/update data.
I think (best practices told the same) that for functional testing you need to stub sphinx calls.